# DisplayObjectContainer into Flex component... how?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I'll re-write this question to be clearer.

I'm trying to get a class file from Flash into Builder.

Everything in that class sits inside a Sprite called `mainContainer`. Now I'm trying to get that `mainContainer' which hold the graphics for the class into a Flex Application.

This is proving to be a problem as their are many various ways of doing it (it seems going by numerous Google searches).

First off I declare an MXML Canvas with an Image inside it (as I read would work):

```
<mx:Canvas x="268" y="10" width="756" height="680" id="canvas">
    <mx:Image id="spriteLayer" x="268" y="0" width="756" height="700" scaleContent="false" autoLoad="true">

    </mx:Image>
</mx:Canvas>}
```

Ok, my plan was then to pass the Image reference her of `spriteLayer` to the class I'm trying to run:

```
            import includes.Spirograph;
            public var spiro:Spirograph = new Spirograph(spriteLayer);
```

Unfortunately it only ever passes `null` into the Spirograph class:

```
        function Spirograph(canvasImage:Image):void
        {   
            this.canvas = canvasImage;
            mainContainer.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
            mainContainer.graphics.drawRect(290, 0, 670, 700);
            mainContainer.graphics.endFill();

            ui.addChild(mainContainer);
            canvas.addChild(ui);
}
```

Not sure what to do.

Many thanks.

Comment: apologies for bad formatting, seems the SO code highlighting isn't working just now.

Comment: @AlexWwhen formatting code use the 'curly bracket' symbol; not the 'quote' symbol.  I reformatted the code in your post.  I'm not sure if it was a temporary issue if you were unaware; but nevertheless it appears we're good now.

Comment: I'm unclear what the problem is.  Your question seems to mix up MXML with ACtionScript as if the lines were running clearly in sync; when that is not possible.  If you could provide some more context or in depth code, it may help.

Comment: I tried the curly bracket symbol. :/ Also updated the q

Comment: hopefully the question is clearer now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to read up on the [Flex Component LifeCycle](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html).  Most likely the spriteLayer component is not yet created or initialized when the `new Spirograph(spriteLayer)` code called.   When is that code called?

The Flex Component LifeCycle is a series of methods and events that create the Flex UI.  You can override these methods, or listen to these events to 'do stuff'.  The canvas and spritelayer will not be created until after the createChildren method is called; and default property values are defined before that happens.

You could override createChildren() and do the initialization there:

```
override protected function createChildren():void{
 super.createChildren()
 spiro  = new Spirograph(spriteLayer);
}
```

or you could listen to the initialize event and set the default in there:

```
<mx:MyParentComponent initialize="onInitialize()">
 <fx:Script>
   protected function onInitialize():void{
    spiro  = new Spirograph(spriteLayer);
  }
 </fx:Script>
</mx:MyParentComponent>
```

As another poster commented, you could also do the initialization (like above) in the creationComplete event, although I would personally recommend against doing that.  The creationComplete event dispatches at the very end of the lifecycle; and most likely the changes you're doing will cause a renderer event to "restart", forcing most of the lifecycle to parse through again; the component would be resized (measure()) and elements repositioned (updateDisplayList()).   Setting default values as early in the lifecycle as possible is recommended.

Comment: This really helped, thaks a lot... one question, how do I now reference the methods in the class with a Flex event (a Button click). I need the button to fire a method in the spiro instance... Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

for flex 4 - use http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/core/SpriteVisualElement.html

your sprite, if its a custom class extending sprite extend SpriteVisualElement instead.
Otherwise just stuff it in a UIComponent, as UIComponent supports addchild, while it can be handled in flex like a normal flex control (addElement) etc.

So far example if this sprite is embedded in a flash swc with the symbol name of SpriteTest.  In flex, you could add it to another component like soo...

in mxml put a UIComponent, give it an id... of say ucSpriteHolder
in script, var mcMySprite:Sprite = new SpriteTest();
ucSpriteHolder.addChild(mcMySprite)

Comment: I'm not using an embedded Sprite. Should I be? Can I not just use the class library? I don't use any designed symbols, it's all code.

Comment: best and easiest way is for your class, extend SpriteVisualElement.  Then you can work with this in Flex just like any other flex component.

Comment: Right thanks for info I realised I shouldn't be using Flex, it's not the right tool for the job in this case. Sticking with Flash hacks for now ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing `public var spiro:Spirograph = new Spirograph(spriteLayer);` right inside the `<fx:Script>` tag, moving it into canvas `creationComplete` event handler should help

Comment: The Initialize event is a much better choice for his initialization; and I explained why in my answer.  Most people seem to use a creationComplete handler as a 'constructor' style variable, when in reality it's not. In this case, it will probably force the main lifecycle methods to execute again, which isn't good for efficiency.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com - i prefer using `creationComplete` for the case i'll need to access real width/height calculated inside the component. However, thanks for the comment, it's a useful optimization for every other case